# Laravel FullText search rank

Tags: php, laravel-4, full-text-search

I am working on FullText Search on my Laravel website.

$terms = 'Laravel Fulltext Search';

```
DB::table('products')->whereRaw("MATCH($columns) AGAINST(? IN BOOLEAN MODE)",   array($terms))->get();
```

I need to get most relevant results first.
Now when i have result that contains Laravel, Fulltext and search it is going somewhere in the middle of returned rows, when upper results contains only one of the words.

I need

1. Results with all three words
2. Results with two of the words
3. Results with only one of the words

How should i rank keywords by relevance?

Should i explode all terms?

Should i use other type of query like `DB::select( DB::raw());` or else

Thank you for your support